# Change sibling class of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in HTML, and need to add styles to some ancestor siblings with CSS (may not be able). Therefore I use Javascript to add classes to the ancestors.

I read that you [can not create a parent selector](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) with CSS.

FROM THIS:

```
    <ul class="monitor">
      <li><span>Servidor 1</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Hardware</span>
            <ul>
              <li>CPU</li>
              <li>Memoria</li>
              <li>Disco</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span>Airviro</span>
            <ul>
              <li class="warning">AVDBM</li>
              <li>COLDB</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Servidor 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Hardware</span>
            <ul>
              <li class="error">CPU</li>
              <li class="warning">Memoria</li>
              <li>Disco</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span>Airviro</span>
            <ul>
              <li>AVDBM</li>
              <li>COLDB</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

TO THIS:

```
    <ul class="monitor">
      <li><span class="warning">Servidor 1</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Hardware</span>
            <ul>
              <li>CPU</li>
              <li>Memoria</li>
              <li>Disco</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span class="warning">Airviro</span>
            <ul>
              <li class="warning">AVDBM</li>
              <li>COLDB</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span class="error">Servidor 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="error">Hardware</span>
            <ul>
              <li class="error">CPU</li>
              <li class="warning">Memoria</li>
              <li>Disco</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span>Airviro</span>
            <ul>
              <li>AVDBM</li>
              <li>COLDB</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**Any elegant solution?**

Comment: It's possible to use jQuery to navigate to a parent... have you tried? Also, please fix the encoded html entities showing in the second code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all some consideration :

### 1.

> add classes to some ancestor siblings with CSS

this doesn't mean anything, you don't add classes with CSS, you style them.

### 2.

I understand you wish to make a tree where, if a child element has the class .waring or .error then you want its parents to get the same class as well. This probably so you can make the text yellow/red for each tree step. So your problem is not just how to address al the parents and add them a class, but also how to style them properly

### Here's what I came out with

YOUR ORIGINAL HTML

```
<ul class="monitor">
  <li><span>Servidor 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Hardware</span>
        <ul>
          <li>CPU</li>
          <li>Memoria</li>
          <li>Disco</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Airviro</span>
        <ul>
          <li class="warning">AVDBM</li>
          <li>COLDB</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Servidor 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Hardware</span>
        <ul>
          <li class="error">CPU</li>
          <li class="warning">Memoria</li>
          <li>Disco</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Airviro</span>
        <ul>
          <li>AVDBM</li>
          <li>COLDB</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

HERE SOME EXTRA CSS

```
.monitor{
    color:#00aa00;
}
.warning{
    color:#ffaa00;
}
.error{
    color:#ff0000;
}
// Notice the rule under here makes everything not warning or error green.
// Try the fiddle without this and you'll see why it's needed
li:not(.warning):not(.error){
    color:#00aa00;
}
```

FINALLY SOME JQUERY

```
// Select all items with warning class
$('.warning').each(function(){
    // for each item select all its parents which are li|ul
    $(this).parents('li, ul').each(function(){
        // for each parent clear all its classes
        $(this).removeClass()
        // then add the warning class
        $(this).addClass('warning')

    })
})
// same for erro AFTER WARNING as it is more relevant
// and should override the warning color
$('.error').each(function(){

    $(this).parents('li, ul').each(function(){

        $(this).removeClass()
        $(this).addClass('error')

    })
})
```

Hope this helps. [HERE IS A WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4K98W/1/)

### EDIT

Fallowing @Jeremy's comment the jQuery could become

```
// Select all items with warning class
$('.warning').each(function(){
    // for each item select all its parents which are li|ul
    $(this).parentsUntil('.monitor', 'li, ul').each(function(){
        // for each parent clear all its classes
        $(this).removeClass()
        // then add the warning class
        $(this).addClass('warning')

    })
})
// same for erro AFTER WARNING as it is more relevant
// and should override the warning color
$('.error').each(function(){

    $(this).parentsUntil('.monitor', 'li, ul').each(function(){

        $(this).removeClass()
        $(this).addClass('error')

    })
})
```

Notes :

- picked 'li, ul' instead of 'span'
- .parentsUntil('.monitor', 'li, ul'), the first element tells when to stop, the second element tells which items select.

[HERE THE UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4K98W/2/)

Comment: First, thanks for the correction, I used a translator to generate that sentence. English is not my native language. However will modify the question to collaborate with the subsequent use of the article.

Comment: Second, the idea is actually propagate to ancestor classes so that will uncover the worst state within each group.

Comment: Be careful using parents('li, ul'), since that will also find ul and li ancestors above your code snippet. That's why I used parentsUntil() in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
$(this).parentsUntil('span', '.monitor').addClass('warning');
```

This would find all the ancestors of type "span" up until the nearest element with the "monitor" class, and add the "warning" class to each.

It's hard to be certain that this will work for you without a little more information about the problem you're trying to solve though.

Comment: $('.warning').parentsUntil('.monitor').addClass('warning');
$('.error').parentsUntil('.monitor').addClass('error').hasClass('warning').removeClass('warning');

Comment: .monitor>li>ul>li>ul>li.error,.error>span{color:red}.monitor>li>ul>li>ul>li.warning,.warning>span{color:orange}

Comment: You don't need the hasClass('warning') -- removeClass('warning') will just do nothing if it doesn't already have the class.